# Get GPS coords with Addresses from CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a script that takes addresses from a CSV, and tries to find the GPS coordinates.

I am still learning Python, so comments as to general formatting (i.e. variable names, function names, etc.) are appreciated, as well as ways to tighten up the code.  (I'm using the csv module and [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/)).

The CSV is a single column of addresses (following are dummy addresses) saved as a `.csv` file:

```
123 Main Street, Chicago, IL 12345
3214 Overland Drive, Los Angeles, CA 49382
29 NE 9th Street, New York, NY 29384
```

And my .py file:

```
import csv
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

ADDRESS_FILE = "Addresses"

def read_csv(file):
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        address_list = list(reader)
    return address_list


def get_lat_lon(address):
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(address)
        return location.latitude, location.longitude
    except Exception:
        return 0, 0


def google_lat_lon(address):
    geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key="xxxxx")
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(address)
        return location.latitude, location.longitude
    except Exception:
        return 0, 0

def find_coordinates(address):
    google_found = ""
    lat, lon = get_lat_lon(address)
    lat, lon = google_lat_lon(address)
    if lat == 0 and lon == 0:
        lat, lon = google_lat_lon(address)
        google_found = "Note: used Google"
    return lat, lon, google_found

def write_file(info):
    with open(ADDRESS_FILE+" with GPS.csv","w", newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
        for line in info:
            writer.writerow(line) 

def main():
    addresses = read_csv(ADDRESS_FILE+".csv")
    address_GPS = []
    for address in addresses:
        addr = address[0].replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
        lat, lon, google_found = find_coordinates(addr)
        address_GPS.append((addr,lat,lon, google_found, '=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/maps/search/"&B1&","&C1,"Link")'))

    for addr in address_GPS:
        print(addr[:len(addr)-1])
    write_file(address_GPS)     


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Preliminary thoughts:

1. `addr = address[0].replace(u'\xa0', u' ')` - I have this because for some reason when reading the CSV, `\xa0` appears in the string, throwing off the lookup. I think it's due to Encoding? I created the CSV in Excel, File-> Save as .CSV (regular `.csv`, not the option for Mac, or whatever else).
2. `except Exception:` - I think I should be more specific here? That's there in case there's no location found with the address.
3. The `if lat == 0 and lon == 0` is there in case the regular geopy lookup doesn't work, I use their Google Maps option.  But say *that* doesn't work, and I want to use Bing or edit the address, there's probably a better way than keep on nesting that `if lat == 0 and lon == 0` part.
4. Is it okay to have my `main()` like I do? Or is it better to keep the lines in `main()` to primarily be function calls?
5. Is it wise/good practice to have a `return a, b, c, ..., z`? Or is it best to return just one or two things per `return`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your questions:

1. No idea :-)
2. Yes, you should be more specific. The easiest way to find out what exception it could raise is to run it without the guard and give it an address you know does not exist (I'm pretty sure the address `"abdjdiehdbdocoegrvdkdoc"` does not exist, for example). Note that you can catch multiple exceptions at once with `except (Exception1, Exception2):` (the parentheses are required) or with multiple `except` blocks (if you need to do different things, depending on the exception type).
3. Yes, your current `if lat == 0 and lon == 0` approach does not scale to additional lookup services. It is also currently slightly broken, since you always use Google (you use the function before the check). You could iterate through a list of lookup functions until you find one that returns valid coordinates:

```
LOOKUP_FUNCS = get_lat_lon, google_lat_lon

def find_coordinates(address, lookup_funcs=LOOKUP_FUNCS):
    for function in lookup_funcs:
        lat, lon = function(address)
        if (lat, lon) != (None, None):
            return lat, lon
    return None, None
```

Note that I assume here that the functions return `None, None`, instead of `0, 0`, which is arguably a better value for something non-existing. Theoretically, some address could actually be at `0, 0`. Note also that `csv.writer` translates `None` to `""`, when writing to a file (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)).

4. A `main` that does as much as yours is fine, IMO, if this is the only thing this script does. But you might still want to rename it to `add_lat_lon(in_file, out_file)` or something like this, to be able to import the actual functionality in some other script.In your new `main` block (or directly under the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard), you could then call that function.
5. It is perfectly fine to return tuples.

Some additional notes:

- You should add [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)s to your functions to document what they do.
- `csv.writer` has a [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) method that allows you to directly pass a list of rows. So you can just do `writer.writerows(info)`.
- Instead of `print(addr[:len(addr)-1])` you can just do `print(addr[:-1])`

Comment: Thanks very much for your thoughts! These all make sense, and I especially like your answer for #3.  However, when I try to implement that, I put `LOOKUP_FUNCS = get_lat_lon, google_lat_lon` at the top (under `ADDRESS_FILE = ...`) but get the error: `NameError: name 'google_lat_lon' is not defined`  do I need to put that somewhere else?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, after all your function definitions (but before the definition of `find_coordinates`). Python executes your file from top to bottom, so this is one of the few places where this actually matters. It needs to be defined when Python executes the function definition, not when the function is run, because it appears in it's signature. This is also why something like `def f(x=[])` can produce some unexpected results, all executions of the function get the same instance of the list, because the header line is executed when the function is defined.